# Opening up a url in a new window - Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, url

I am converting a site right now, and I can't seem to figure out how to open a new window. I have a form, and when I click submit, it goes to my "membershipRenewalPrint" function in the controller. Inside my controller is this:

```
        $data['orderDrilldown'] = $this->MiscTools->orderDrilldown(reset($_POST));
        $this->load->view('pages/members/includes/membership_renewal_print',array_merge($data, $this->data));
```

What is the proper way of getting this to load in a new window?

Thanks,
Austin

Comment: do you want submit form and open new window?

Comment: yes, is that handled in the controller or in my view?

Comment: you have to handled in view. And also my solution will do open in new tab not window.

Comment: So you want the response of the form to be shown in a popup or something?

Answer (score 1):

you have to target in form tag.

```
<form target="_blank" .....>
```

In CI,

```
$attributes = array('target' => '_blank', 'id' => 'myform');

echo form_open('ACTION_URL', $attributes);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write:

`echo form_open('ACTION_URL', array('target'=>'_blank', 'id'=>'myform'));`